# sending out messages simultaneously python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, concurrency, simultaneous

I created 10 user accounts for an application that we have
and i would like to have all these 10 users send out messages simultaneously.

so i made 10 .py scripts, in each script there is just a system call that passes `

```
"name of app cli client, some parameters including email and message"
```

to bash, then I run all of them from bash in one command using `&` 
and my question is how can I do this but do it better?

how can I send out 10 messages in parallel from bash? without creating 10 individual .py scripts? any help would be nice^^

Comment: `how can I do this but do it better` : what are your criteria of acceptation ? What don't you like about the default behaviour of `&` ? If your scripts are a simple echo, the result should be pretty much instant.

Comment: Create a list of dictionary of the parameters and loop on it.  This way, 1 python script builds the 10 system calls and executes them.

Comment: I'd like to have these 10 users all send out a message simultaneously without having to create 10 individual scripts for each one user.. and my scripts are just a subprocess.check_output() with just that command in my question

Comment: Well, using a loop is not "simultaneous" theoretically, but it will be very close.  Looping on 10 items is not an atomic action, but it is *very* small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import threading,os

ten_python_scripts = [] # mention all files here

def func(filename):
  x = subprocess.call("python {}".format(filename), shell=True)

threads = []
for filename in ten_python_scripts:
  x = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(filename,))
  threads.append(x)
for thread in threads:
  thread.start()
for thread in threads:
  thread.join()
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer!!! but would it also work if i just use 10 strings (my commands as strings) instead of all the file names?  in `ten_python_scripts` ,

Comment: when I write my commands as strings it attempts to read them as file names even though they are enclosed in single quotes, what could i change so that it knows they are strings and not file names? I'm really a noob programmer and never worked with threading

Comment: can you share some code, i am not able to understand. for threading follow this tutorial https://www.simplifiedpython.net/python-threading-example/

Comment: i used your code but i kept strings in my list like this `ten_python_scripts = ["bash command 1",  "bash command 2"] ...` ( my bash commands starts with `"cd ~/app-cli && some parameteres"`) and when i run my script i get: `python: can't open file 'cd': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'cd': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: cd is a program, which is in /usr/bin, i think you should mention /usr/bin/cd instead of cd @skdadle

Comment: i kept the absolute path in my strings like this `/home/pi/app-cli/app&& bash app` but now i get `/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/home/pi/app-cli'` , my bash command just starts with cd ~/app-cli directory so i thought putting the absolute path would be okay. i tried with  `/usr/bin/cd`
but i got same error `python: can't open file '/usr/bin/cd': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: i figured out what i was doing wrong, i should change `python {}` to just `{}` if i want to run strings  :D thank you so much!!

Comment: could you explain your piece of code a little? I used it, it works, but even after researching about it idk exactly what it does, does it start multiple threads? or is it just 1 thread, and does it utilize all 4 cores or just 1? and what does threads.append(x) mean? i'm really a noob so I would appreciate any clarification, thanks youu ^^